# Compiz causes Out of memory when Ubuntu left for around 2h inactive

Tags: suspend, compiz, power-management

I'm struggling with hanging GUI interface in Ubuntu 17.04 when left inactive and unattended for longer period of time (around 2 hours).

In the dmesg I can read:

```
[ 5499.511514] Out of memory: Kill process 2441 (compiz) score 825 or sacrifice child
[ 5499.511564] Killed process 2441 (compiz) total-vm:8363308kB, anon-rss:7101744kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:5816kB
```

The machine is Lenovo Yoga (i5, integrated Intel graphics), OS version is 4.10.0-35-generic.

I've installed TLP power management. According to the power management settings, my PC should suspend in 1 hour but it does not. Instead it hangs GUI.

Thank you in advance for any help,

Regards,

P.

Comment: This looks like OOM Killer chose to terminate compiz - what processes are you running that might be consuming lots of memory?

Comment: There were no foreground apps other just a couple of desktop plugins (i.s. system load indicator, plank).

Comment: Apparently something in your setup is causing a memory leak.

Comment: Possibly. After recent updates the problem seems not to occur anymore, but I have no idea actually what helped.